# Setting up wireless router without Internet connection

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router

I've recently purchased a Netgear wireless router and would like to set it up at home to connect my computers via wireless with each other. When I access the wireless router the first time to configure it, it tries to establish an internet connection with the modem first before it allows me to interact with it. I don't have an active internet connection at the moment.

Is there any way that I can still set up my wireless home network?

Additional info:

I did connect to the router via 192.168.1.1 as the manual suggested and via wire. The setup then proceeds to looking for an active internet connection and won't let me do anything else until a connection is found (except for abort. Thank you, Netgear.) I'm on a Windows (7/XP) environment. The router is a **Netgear WGR614GR Wireless Cabel/DSL Router**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most consumer routers<sup>1</sup> will function as a DHCP server + switch by default even without an internet connection.

- Connect a *wired* ethernet cable from your computer to the router
- Connect it to the LAN, the ports numbered 1,2,3,4.  The WAN port is usually demarcated by color or location.
- You may want to check if your network card is set to DHCP, `Start -> Run -> ncpa.cpl -> right click NIC -> Properties -> Internet Protocol (TCP/IP) -> Properties`
- Browse to the router's default page, sometimes http://192.168.1.100, http://192.168.1.1
- Log in, [list of some router default passwords](http://www.phenoelit-us.org/dpl/dpl.html)

What is your router model?  I assumed a Windows environment; indicate if otherwise.

---

<sup>(1) Cisco's tend to come w/ interfaces down.  It would be rare to consider them "consumer" but they're moving in that direction (Valet), so I can't speak for those.</sup>

Comment: It's 192.168.1.1 - I did connect to that as the manual suggested and via wire. The setup then proceeds to looking for an active internet connection and won't let me do anything else until a connection is found. Yes, I'm on a Windows (7/XP) environment. The router is a Netgear WGR614GR Wireless Cabel/DSL Router

Comment: Interesting. Can you bypass the wizard? http://192.168.1.1/basicsetting.htm, http://www.routerlogin.com/CA_HiddenPage.htm, http://192.168.1.1/CA_HiddenPage.htm

Comment: Are these urls valid or are you guessing? Bypassing would be wonderful. I'll try these when I get home.

Comment: I know some models can bypass the "SmartWizard" (http://kb.netgear.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/978), but the correct link depends on your firmware.

Comment: BTW, I believe routerlogin.net and .com are both owned by netgear and the routers capture that domain name as their internal address.

Comment: 192.168.1.1/basicsetting.htm was spot-on - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After some experimentation with the router last night i tried to set it up to a device with a static IP adress for the WAN and it of cours was happy when connected to something, yay but it won't normally so what i did was plug it into itself from the modem port to the LAN 1 port and use the same static IP adress and presto it is happy. The only doen side being i am out a single Lan Port but i Really only need 2-3 anywho so i am golden.

Try that and as long as you don't need all 4 Lan ports you can start to run your devices over the network without then constatnly getting kicked off (because they no longer get sent to the set up page)

Good Luck
Hope it works for you

Answer (score 0):

There is absolutely NO reason at all that a router should have to have an active internet
connection on the WAN side in order to setup the router on the LAN side.

That smells of how a Trojan Horse virus works.

I've got a Linksys router right now that's doing just that. The router seems to be borked.

MODEL# WRT1200RT V2

Hopefully, I'm wrong about it being borked.